# IIS URL rewrite subfolder to other url

Tags: url, redirect, iis

I have a website running on a load balanced environment using 2 Azure servers. I have two end points which allow me to connect to each server separately

e.g.

- www.url.com:801 - goes to server 1
- www.url.com:802 - goes to server 2

Website uses CKFinder for uploading files to the server, via www.url.com/ckfinder.

This of course creates a problem as when user opens www.url.com/ckfinder the response can come from the server 1 or the server 2 and of course uploaded file is going to be stored only on server 1 or server 2

Is it possible to create an IIS url rewrite rule on the server 1 which will every request to the specific URL redirect to other URL

Example

User calls www.url.com/ckfinder, LB redirects the request to the server 2 - server 2 serves the request

User calls again www.url.com/ckfinder, this time LB redirects request to the server 1, IIS on the server1 redirects user to www.url.com:802/ckfinder

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure HTTP Redirection on IIS. Type in google how to configure http request on IIS and you will find plenty of helpful websites.

In order to do this. Enable HTTP Redirection feature under Common HTTP Features (Use this [Link for step by step guide](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect)